# Background media image in twig

Tags: twig, drupal-8

We're using Media Library (Drupal8) and want to use an image as background with it's related image style

```
style="background-image: url('{{ file_url(content.field_header_image[0]['#markup'] ) }}');
```

This is the code we're using right now for field_image. It works great, prints the image as background with its image style associated

We want the same for field that is a reference to a Media Entity.
We don't want to manually render the Image Style with Twig Tweak, because that is already defined in Drupal Content Type, we don't want to be repeating information and making it harder to change in the future

Comment: This should address it. https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_image/issues/2856093. Also, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229402/how-to-get-media-entity-image-entity-reference-field-url-in-twig-theme.

Comment: @EternalHour I saw those (thanks for helping!). The issue I have with them is that they hardcode the ImageStyle, so if you change it on the backend in Drupal, it won't impact, because you're rendering a hardcodede ImageStyle. So far I haven't found any solution, all of them involve TwigTweak or preprocess but in all of them the IS is hardocoded.

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me

```
 {{ file_url(paragraph.field_custom_image.entity.field_media_image.entity.fileuri) }}
```

here I have done with the media field from the paragraph field. `field_custom_image` is a field name in my paragraph template

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I 've got the media url here

```
media_entity = content.field_hero_background.0['#media']
```

then

```
image_uri = media_entity.field_media_image.entity.fileuri
```

The completed code is

```
{% if content.field_hero_background.0['#media'] %}
        {% set media_entity = content.field_hero_background.0['#media'] %}
        {% set image_uri = media_entity.field_media_image.entity.fileuri %}
        <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back" style="background-image: url('{{ file_url(image_uri) }}');">
        </div>
{% endif %}
```